# Group sales by day of the week

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which looks something like this

```
sell_price double        buy_price double      time int(11)
31.5                     20.5                  1353755931 (2012-11-27)
20                       10.5                  1353755235 (2012-11-27)
40                       30                    1353752531 (2012-11-26)
50                       25                    1353751237 (2012-11-26)
40                       10                    1353745609 (2012-11-25)
```

And I am trying to group all values to get the sales for each day of the week, the desired table should look like the following:

```
sell_price double        buy_price double      time int(11)
51.5                     30.5                  1353755931 (2012-11-27)
90                       55                    1353755931 (2012-11-26)
40                       10                    1353755931 (2012-11-25)
```

I tried the following query but I seem to have a problem with grouping

```
SELECT sell_price, buy_price, time 
FROM sales 
GROUP BY DAY(time) 
ORDER BY time DESC
```

The above query returns only 1 row

```
31.5       20.5      1353755931
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: Yes it's a unix timestamp (the above table is an example)

Comment: how do you know `1353755931` and `1353755235` is saved on 2012-11-27?

Comment: @KuyaJohn looks that way - what is the `(YYYY-MM-DD)` doing in there?

Comment: the (YYYY-MM-DD) is just to be used as an example, the timestamp is what is in the database

Comment: So, how do you want to aggregate the grouped prices?

Comment: wish that time column was saved as a `datetime`

Comment: can you check the time on desired output?

Comment: I'm surprised that's not an error, doing a `GROUP BY` for something that isn't `SELECT`ed.  You need to have `DAY(time)` in your `SELECT` and then `ORDER BY DAY(time) DESC`.  You are never interested in `time` in its untransformed form.  Also, the problem could be that `time` is a reserved word in SQL, and you should rename that column.

Comment: @KuyaJohn I just added it the question, I only get the first row of the table returned

Comment: @AndyLester, you can order and group by terms that do not appear in the select list.

Comment: the problem is all of them were just one date at different time, how did the result came up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) time,
       SUM(sell_price),
       SUM(buy_price)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time))
```

Comment: its not giving the expected results. Check this fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62b50/1

Comment: @AnandPhadke yes, the problem is all of them were just one date (`November, 24 2012`) at different time, do you know how did the result came up?

Comment: @AnandPhadke Sorry to break it to you but my test timestamps were made up

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/273ef/1),

```
SELECT
            sell_price,
            buy_price,
            time,
            day(time)
    FROM
        sales
```

`day(time)` evaluates to `null` and, since you specify no aggratetion functions for the prices you get just the first row of everything.

If you examine [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/273ef/8).

```
SELECT
            sell_price,
            buy_price,
            date(from_unixtime(time))
    FROM
        sales;
```

You'll see that all your data is on the same day, assuming those numbers are valid unix times.